# Java AWT Window doesn't get repainted

Tags: java, awt, repaint

I've derived a class from window, but whenever I call setValue() (which calls repaint) it doesn't get redrawn (the method is called, but nothing changes on the screen). The first value is drawn, which is 0 by default.
Here's the class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Window;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HashtagLikeDisplay extends Window {

    protected int count;

    HashtagLikeDisplay() throws HeadlessException {
        super(null);

        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setBounds(this.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); // Doesn't matter if this is here or not

        Font font = getFont().deriveFont(48f);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        String message = "Total: " + Integer.toString(count);
        g.drawString(message, 10, 58);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void setCount(int c) {
        this.count = c;
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Why does it not get repainted properly?

Comment: Not sure, but can you try adding super.paint(g) at the start of your paint method?

Comment: So it's getting painted, but it's not updating, correct?

Comment: Yes, I guess. If I do a println in the paint, the message gets printed when expected to repaint. But nothing changes on the screen.

Comment: You should extend `Frame` instead of `Window`.

Comment: I've tried it, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the oracle docs

> If [the update] method is reimplemented, super.update(g) should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered. If a child component is entirely clipped by the current clipping setting in g, update() will not be forwarded to that child.

Also, call super.paint(g) in paint() just as the first commenter said.

If it still doesn't work, you should use Swing, like a JComponent instead of window.

```
public class HashtagLikeDisplay extends JComponent {
...

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Customize after calling super.paintComponent(g)

    Font font = getFont().deriveFont(48f);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    String message = "Total: " + Integer.toString(count);
    g.drawString(message, 10, 58);
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Can I achieve the same with a JComponent (no border, fully transparent, so I basicly draw onto the screen)?

Comment: @CodezMe You can make it transparent, you have to set the alpha value to 0.0 when you construct the Color of your component.

Comment: @CodezMe to remove the border, i believe you can call `setBorder(null)`

Comment: I just called setUndecorated(true), works like a charm with Swing. Thank you!

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.